# Ray-Box (AABB) is slower than without

Tags: hlsl, bounding-boxes, intersection, raytracing

I'm trying to write my own ray tracer. The last days I tried implementing a bounding box algorithm for it. But I'm getting a much slower frame rate with the bounding boxes turned on. I think it has something to do with checking the box with every ray but I don't know how I could change that.

Here is my code for the intersection algorithm:

```
bool Intersect(Ray r, float3 lb, float3 rt)
{
    float3 dir_inv = 1 / r.direction;
    
    double t1 = (lb[0] - r.origin[0]) * dir_inv[0];
    double t2 = (rt[0] - r.origin[0]) * dir_inv[0];

    double tmin = min(t1, t2);
    double tmax = max(t1, t2);

    for (int i = 1; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        t1 = (lb[i] - r.origin[i]) * dir_inv[i];
        t2 = (rt[i] - r.origin[i]) * dir_inv[i];

        tmin = max(tmin, min(t1, t2));
        tmax = min(tmax, max(t1, t2));
    }

    return tmax > max(tmin, 0.0);
}
```

My trace function:

```
RayHit Trace(Ray ray)
{
    RayHit bestHit = CreateRayHit();
    uint count, stride, i;

    // Trace ground plane
    IntersectGroundPlane(ray, bestHit);

    // Trace spheres
    _Spheres.GetDimensions(count, stride);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (Intersect(ray, _Spheres[i].position - (_Spheres[i].radius), _Spheres[i].position + (_Spheres[i].radius)))
            IntersectSphere(ray, bestHit, _Spheres[i]);
    }
    
    // Trace mesh objects
    _MeshObjects.GetDimensions(count, stride);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        //if (Intersect(ray, float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), float3(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f)))
            //IntersectMeshObject(ray, bestHit, _MeshObjects[i]);
    }

    return bestHit;
}
```

Comment: At least from my experience, GPUs aren't great with doubles, have you tried changing the values inside `Intersect` to floats?

Comment: It looks like you also have opportunities to vectorize the `Intersect` method, rather than iterating over x, y, and z serially.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 it seems like you were also right because by replacing it with floats it still got much faster (still not as fast as without but still fast)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the bounding boxes on sphere primitives.

A sphere intersection is *very* cheap, as computer graphics operations go. In fact, it's often substantially *cheaper* than testing against a bounding box (one slightly more complicated check instead of 3 simple ones), so using a bounding box to save sphere checks is rather like taking out $100 of insurance on a $20 trinket.

For every ray that misses the sphere, you end up paying the bounding box test cost, which is more expensive than testing the sphere directly. And for every ray that hits the sphere (ore misses but comes close enough to hit the box), you pay both the bounding box test cost *and* the sphere test cost.

Where bounding box checks can help you are...

- Situations where the check it lets you skip is much more expensive than a simple box (like a triangle mesh or implicit surface)
- Situations where a bounding box test rejection lets you skip a whole bunch of objects (like if you had a group of spheres or other primitives in a single bounding box for the whole collection, or using a hierachical space partition that lets you skip whole swaths of your scene)

Comment: Oh thank you, I havent thought about this Im sure this is the problem. Thanks